# Set Select query results as array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, loops, foreach

I currently have this query that returns an array, however how to I output this array simply as Thomas, James. As I want to store it in that format within a variable I can call later. Is it a foreach? Thanks

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT admin_name FROM adminuser_tbl");
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
         print_r($row);
    }
}
```

**This outputs:**

```
Array ( [admin_name] => Thomas [0] => Thomas ) Array ( [admin_name] => James [0] => James )
```

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
print_r($row);
```

How about...

```
$name = join(", ", $row);
```

Or you could concatenate the results to an array of names

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT admin_name FROM adminuser_tbl");
$names = array();
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $names[] = join(", ", $row);
    }
}
```